# Adding Facebook's Like button inside iOS WebView

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, authentication, facebook-like

I use a UIWebView to run the facebook code. The problem is that the WebView is not authenticated in facebook so a login is required.

My user is already logged in to facebook using the native API (that uses Safari).

How can I authenticate the user in the webview in the background using the access-token so that when the "like" is displayed the user is already authenticated?

Load the html code below once and perform the login. Session information is stored and the like button will work fine. 
Clean your facebook cookies and reload the html. The session is loaded from the localStorage but Login is required again.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />    
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.cdnjs.com/ajax/libs/json2/20110223/json2.js"></script>  
</head>
<body onload="onload()">
    Hello Facebook, can you hear me?

    <div id="fb-root" >     
        <fb:like href='http://www.stackoverflow.com' send='true' layout='button_count' width='220' show_faces='true' font='arial' ref='dropalert'></fb:like>        
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function onload() {         
            var session = null;
            var sessionStr = localStorage.getItem("session");
            if (sessionStr){
                session = JSON.parse(sessionStr);
                alert("stored session " + sessionStr);
            }
            else {
                alert("session not stored");
            }
            FB.init({
                appId   : <your-app-id>,
                session : session,        
                cookie  : true,                     
                xfbml   : true              
            });

            FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
                alert("getLoginStatus");                
                if (response.status == "connected") {
                    alert("Logged in");
                    parseFBML();
                } 
                else {
                    // no user session available, someone you dont know
                    alert("NOT Logged in");
                    login();
                }               
            });
        }

        function login() {
            alert("login starting");
            // Login to facebook to get an access-token
            FB.login(function (response) {  
                if (response.session) {
                    var sessionStr = JSON.stringify(response.session)
                    alert("session: \n\n" + sessionStr + "\n\n\n\n");
                    localStorage.setItem("session", sessionStr);                    
                } 
                else {
                    alert("Login failed");
                }
            }, {scope:'publish_stream,offline_access'});
        }    

        function parseFBML() {
            FB.XFBML.parse(document.getElementById('fb-root'));
        }       
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this is an option for you but, if you can pass a session parameter to your web content you can use it to initialise the JavaScript SDK within your web content.

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
<script>
  FB.init({
    appId  : <my-app-id>,
    session : { "uid":"<users facebook id>", "access_token":"<valid access token>", "expires": <expires value>, "sig":"<valid signature>"},
    cookie : true, 
    xfbml  : true
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, but this doesnt seem to work. I clean the facebook cookies and try to use the session value. If I call FB.login the login form is displayed. If I try to active the API a no "access_token" error is returned. Any other idea? how do you connect with a valid session?

Comment: Your session should contain a valid access token. How are you generating the session parameter?

Comment: I currently test in a browser. I call FB.init and then FB.login (with offline access perms). I print out the access_token and the session-key. I clean the Cookies, set session-key to the FB.init session attribute. I do not call login and try to access the API. It fails. I tried to set the access_token value in the session attribute as you mentioned above - also fails.

Comment: Thanks, API can be accessed now, but "like" still requeries login. I updated my question with the details.

Comment: Are you using the XFBML or iFrame version of the like button?

Comment: Have you tried using some of the other typical session variables like uid & sig?

Comment: Yes, I used the localStorage to store a JSON.stringify of the session. In the 2nd run, I parsed it and tried to use it, but didnt work.

Comment: @jBit let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2025/discussion-between-totach-and-jbit)